# Magento currency switcher not working in home page

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, switcher

In my magento site currency switcher is not working in home page only but after clearing cache only switching currency in home page
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to block cache.

To fix this behaviour you need to disable caching for this particular block. It can be done by adding **cache_lifetime="1"** parameter to our shortcode.